# Mobile Safari reflow bug while using CSS3's media queries

Tags: ios, ipad, css, mobile-safari

I'm developing a site that will be visualized on iPad's Mobile Safari and standard PC's browsers.
To adapt my layout (especially a  to the mobile browser, I'm using this CSS3 media query:

```
    @media only screen and (max-width: 980px), only screen and (max-device-width: 1185px) {
        #galleria {
        margin-left:5%;
        margin-top:15%;
        }
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 1185px), only screen and (max-device-width: 980px) {
        #galleria {
        margin-left:16%;
        margin-top:15%;
        }
    }
```

This method works, but when I rotate my device, the bugs comes out.
Basically in this page there's a  called "logo" that represent an image, here's its CSS:

```
    #logo {
        position:absolute;
        top:30px;
        left:26%;
    }

    #logo img {
        width:75%;
    }
```

This image for each time that I rotate the device, becomes more smaller.
How can I avoid this bug?
Thanks for all the answers!

Comment: What meta viewport do you use ?

Comment: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,user-scalable=no">

Comment: It may be an occurence of the famous orientation bug (http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/iphone-safari-viewport-scaling-bug/comment-page-1) Could you please provide an exemple or screenshots ?

Comment: Landscape [link](http://postimage.org/image/igtmt2qop/) Portrait [link](http://postimage.org/image/brn3d25cp/) Landscape again, see the smaller logo [link](http://postimage.org/image/i7w235dw9/). I've tried the solutions provided with that link but no luck.

Comment: Now that's a curious bug. I've no idea what's causing it. Maybe you could avoid it with a min-width on the logo, but that's only a poor workaround.

Comment: Resolved using "position: relative" in the "#logo" CSS block

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a percent based width it's not becoming smaller, your screen is becoming bigger... it's ratio has not changed... that said, if you don't wish it to change size you can either not hard-code in a pixel size, instead of a percent size... or you can have javascript calculate the percent and convert it to a pixel size then load that in as the variable so once the screen is rotated it won't update to a new ("smaller illusion") size.

Comment: Just saw the photos you uploaded after this in your comments, I have no clue what could be causing that, I wasn't aware that it kept shrinking! That's crazy! Good luck!